# Why isn't my unit container running?

Tags: debian, systemd, containers, podman

I'm trying to move the manual launch of our Podman LakeFS container to a service at boot.

I was suggested to use Quadlet and I'm following this [guide](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/quadlet-podman)

I converted our script/command:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
podman run --pull=newer\
  --name lakeFS \
  -p 8000:8000 \
  -e LAKEFS_DATABASE_TYPE="postgres" \
  -e LAKEFS_DATABASE_POSTGRES_CONNECTION_STRING="postgres://lakefs:lakefs@192.168.11.104:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable" \
  -e LAKEFS_AUTH_ENCRYPT_SECRET_KEY=".." \
  -e LAKEFS_BLOCKSTORE_TYPE="s3" \
  -e LAKEFS_BLOCKSTORE_S3_FORCE_PATH_STYLE="true" \
  -e LAKEFS_BLOCKSTORE_S3_ENDPOINT="http://192.168.17.107:9000" \
  -e LAKEFS_BLOCKSTORE_S3_DISCOVER_BUCKET_REGION="false" \
  -e LAKEFS_BLOCKSTORE_S3_CREDENTIALS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=".." \
  -e LAKEFS_BLOCKSTORE_S3_CREDENTIALS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=".." \
  docker.io/treeverse/lakefs:latest run
```

to an unit file (`/usr/share/containers/systemd/lakeFS.container`) using [podlet](https://crates.io/crates/podlet):

```
[Container]
ContainerName=lakeFS
Environment=LAKEFS_DATABASE_TYPE=postgres LAKEFS_DATABASE_POSTGRES_CONNECTION_STRING=postgres://lakefs:lakefs@192.168.11.104:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable LAKEFS_AUTH_ENCRYPT_SECRET_KEY=.. LAKEFS_BLOCKSTORE_TYPE=s3 LAKEFS_BLOCKSTORE_S3_FORCE_PATH_STYLE=true LAKEFS_BLOCKSTORE_S3_ENDPOINT=http://192.168.17.107:9000 LAKEFS_BLOCKSTORE_S3_DISCOVER_BUCKET_REGION=false LAKEFS_BLOCKSTORE_S3_CREDENTIALS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=.. LAKEFS_BLOCKSTORE_S3_CREDENTIALS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=..
Exec=run
Image=docker.io/treeverse/lakefs:latest
PublishPort=8000:8000
Pull=newer
```

but after trying to inform `systemd` about it with
`systemctl daemon-reload`

I still get:

```
~$ systemctl status lakeFS.service 
× lakeFS.service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/share/containers/systemd/lakeFS.container; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-01-24 15:25:22 CET; 4min 20s ago
   Duration: 680ms
    Process: 1738 ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman run --name=lakeFS --cidfile=/run/lakeFS.cid --replace --rm --cgroups=split --sdnotify=conmon -d --publish 8000:8000 --env>
    Process: 1816 ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/podman rm -v -f -i --cidfile=/run/lakeFS.cid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1738 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 14.026s
```

What is wrong?

Ps: Podman version is 4.9.0

Comment: What is your `podman --version`?

Comment: Why are you running `systemctl --user`? It looks like you are creating system containers. Also: It's not a problem, but arguably you should be placing your container files in `/etc/containers/systemd` (typically, `/usr/share/containers/systemd` would be used for container files provided by installed packages).

Comment: See [my answer to a different quadlet question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77867689/147356) for some suggestions on debugging things.

Comment: I got 4.9 version, I'm running `systemctl --user` because that's what the guide suggested. I'll try the second location

Comment: @larsks I added the debug, it looks apparently fine, but I don't see the service

Comment: Try without `--user`. `systemctl --user` expects config files in `~/.config/containers/systemd/`.

Comment: Ok, just tried, same error, service doesn't start

Comment: `code=exited, status=1/FAILURE` means that the program in the container started but exited with the return code 1. You need to debug why your application is exiting.

Comment: @AlexD application starts fine from script, maybe the problem lies in the unit file? Does Podlet convert it properly?

Comment: Try running the command from 'ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman run' manually to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your version of `podman` doesn't have `quadlet` integrated. `Quadlet` was integrated into `podman` version 4.4 and Debian `bookworm` contains `podman` version 4.3.1. In this case, you need to install `quadlet` separately.

Comment: No, sorry, I didn't specify, but I do have 4.9.0